# Limiting Registered User to their own unique Folder on File Manager

Tags: dotnetnuke

We are using DNN 6.2 and are attempting to limit Registered Users so they can upload content to their own Unique Folder.  We are not wanting to do this by user role.

Some examples where this is an issue are when a Registered User is uploading content using the wysiwyg, or when using the DNN module Form and List.  Currently all Users can see all content on the portal.  The goal is for the user to only see their own uploaded content.

Also, we would be open to purchasing a module if that is the simplest way to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible out of the box. You can implement your own folder provider based on existing one to do this. Look at [this article](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Wiki/Page/Folder-providers.aspx) for more help